# What do phrasal verb do you use for the act of cutting or copy pasting on Photoshop?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, verbs, phrasal-verbs

> This man looks like it was cut off and then pasted onto the picture.
> The rest of the image looks like it was drawn with crayons while the
> man looks like it was taken from a photograph.

What do phrasal verb do you use for the act of cutting or copy pasting on Photoshop?

I am not sure if you should use "cut off" or "cut out" and if there's a simpler phrasal verb for "pasted onto". What are the various options?

Comment: People use "photoshop" as a verb these days - not in formal writing, but in casual speech. You could say, "it looks like the man was photoshopped in."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb [edit](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/edit) is used in the phrasal verbs *edit in* and *edit out*, which means "added in", and "removed out" respectively.

The sentence could be written as

> This man looks like it was *edited into* the picture.

These phrasal verbs are not used exclusively with images though, they are also used with text, film, etc.

---

As pointed out in a comment, you can also use *to photoshop* itself as a verb to mean "editing an image". This is very similar to how the verb *to google* means "look for something on the internet using a search engine".

In that case, the sentence would be

> This man looks like it was *photoshopped into* the picture.